# Can't mount networked Windows external drive via cifs

Tags: networking, 16.04, mount, samba, cifs

Ever since I did the Windows 10 Anniversary Update, I've been having issues mounting an external drive plugged into a Windows machine on my network.

My `fstab`:

```
//bowser.local/Fire  /media/Fire  cifs  auto,_netdev,comment=systemd.automount,sec=ntlm,uid=cameron,credentials=/root/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0755,dir_mode=0755,defaults  0  0
```

I get the error:

```
mount error(5): Input/output error
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

I've searched around and tried a bunch of different options (my options didn't start that long!).

The thing is, **it works fine with other shares**. I tried sharing `Desktop` from the `C` drive on Windows just to test and it works fine, so I know it's not bad credentials or that it can't find the PC on the network or something... it appears to be something specific about the external drive? Well, drives... I have two I'm trying to mount and both have this same issue.

If I try the GUI and use "Connect to Server" in Nautilus to comment to `smb://bowser.local`, the `Fire` share shows up there, but if I click on it, I get the error:

```
Unhandled error message: Failed to mount Windows share: Invalid argument
```

The `Desktop` share works fine.

Don't know if it helps, but on my Mac, going to `Shared > bowser > Fire` in Finder works fine, too.

As mentioned, using Windows 10 with the Anniversary Update:

- Windows 10 Enterprise 14393
- Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop
- Mac OS X 10.11.6

**Update:** Thanks to emk2203's comment, I got a new error trying to connect directly with `smbclient`: `tree connect failed: NT_STATUS_INSUFF_SERVER_RESOURCES`.

This led to more evidence that it was Windows' fault and a friend suggested I looked in logs. In the Windows logs, I found this error:

> The server's configuration parameter "irpstacksize" is too small for the server to use a local device.  Please increase the value of this parameter.

Comment: What do you get if you use `smbclient` to connect to the server? `smbclient -L //bowser.local` to list the available shares, if "Fire" is there, `smbclient //bowser.local/Fire` to connect. Do a `ls` within `smbclient` to see if the connection is valid.

Comment: @emk2203 So `Fire` _is_ listed, but when I try to connect, I get this error: `tree connect failed: NT_STATUS_INSUFF_SERVER_RESOURCES`. That's at least a new error to explore! **Edit:** Connecting to `Desktop` (on `C`) works, just not `Fire` (an external drive).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to the `irpstacksize` error I discovered in the Windows logs, I was able to find [an article](http://winhlp.com/node/40?page=4) that talked about how to increase that value (putting the gist of it below in case the link breaks).

It's a registry entry (edit via `regedit`) (create it if it doesn't exist--it did not exist for me):

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
 \SYSTEM
  \CurrentControlSet
   \Services
    \LanmanServer
     \Parameters
IRPStackSize DWORD 0x0000000f (15)
```

`IRPStackSize` is *case sensitive*. Decimal 15 is the default. They say to increase it to 5 until (50 is the max?). I couldn't find any evidence that increasing it to 50 would have any real negative consequences (and most people seemed to believe it won't), so after it still wasn't working at 33, I jumped to 50 and it *worked*!

In between each change you need to restart `Services > Server` for the change to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

Moin, I had the same problem. 
After long search at google, I found the error by my self.

The Anniversary Update changed my network-firewall-state to public, so it blocks everything. After I changed it back to privat it was solved.

Greets from Berlin.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still set to private and file sharing is indeed enabled. Firewall wouldn't explain why `C` drive folders work, but not external drives. I appreciate your response, especially cuz it looked like you signed up for an account just to try and help! :-)